# How do I know that `ThisWorkbook` is a `Workbook`?

Tags: c#, com, vbe, vbide

I'm working with the VBIDE API, and can't assume that the host application is Excel, or any Office app either.

So all I know is that I'm looking at a `VBComponent`, and that its `Type` is `vbext_ct_document`.

In the VBE's *immediate pane* I can get this output:

```
?TypeName(Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1"))
VBComponent
?TypeName(Sheet1)
Worksheet
```

But the `Sheet1` object only exists in the runtime environment, so if I'm a C# add-in I don't even see it.

The only thing that gets anywhere close to what I need, is via the `Parent` and `Next` properties of the component:

```
?TypeName(Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").Properties("Parent").Object)
Workbook
?TypeName(Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").Properties("Next").Object)
Worksheet
```

This gets me the type names I'm after... but on the wrong component! And for `ThisWorkbook`, which is the top-level document object, I get the `Application` object as the `Parent`:

```
?TypeName(Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").Properties("Parent").Object)
Application
```

The approach is *potentially* useful, but *only if I hard-code host-specific logic* that knows that whichever component has a "Parent" property of type "Application" is a `Workbook` instance when the host application is Excel... and there's no guarantee that other document modules in other hosts will even have that "Parent" property, so I'm pretty much stumped.

I'm open to literally *anything* - from p/invoke calls and low-level COM "reflection" magic (the `ITypeInfo` kind of magic) to ... to... I don't know - `unsafe` code with funky pointers that will require `// here be dragons` comments - any *lead* that can potentially end up a working solution is welcome.

---

AFAIK the VBE add-in lives in the same process as the host, so *somewhere* there's a pointer to `ThisWorkbook` and `Sheet1` and whatever other document-type `VBComponent` in the VBA project.

```
?ObjPtr(ThisWorkbook)
 161150920
```

I think I just need to grab that pointer *somehow* and I'll be where I need to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately the values/objects of the vbComponent Properties collection are only a reflection of the CoClass's instance values, so they're not reliable across all VBA hosts. For example, you can't *know* that the `Parent` property will exist in the Properties collection.

When a host supports document-type-components, it is up to the host to define the GUID of the Interface that the document is supporting. The host will usually also be responsible for creating/removing the actual document, just as only the Excel object model can add a sheet to a workbook, while VBIDE cannot.

You've talked about Workbooks and Worksheets, so I'll include both....

Unfortunately, VBIDE conceals some of the details about document-type components, and it deliberately omits these details when exporting a module, and even converts the exported document-type module into class module text, like this `Worksheet` called `Sheet1`, so that it *can't* be reimported as a document-type module:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Sheet1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Sub Foo()

End Sub
```

Compare the above, to the document-module text that is actually stored (in compressed format) inside the `Sheet1` module:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Sheet1"
Attribute VB_Base = "0{00020820-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Attribute VB_TemplateDerived = False
Attribute VB_Customizable = True
Sub Foo()

End Sub
```

Note the 3 additional attributes that exist in the *real* module text:

```
Attribute VB_Base = "0{00020820-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
Attribute VB_TemplateDerived = False
Attribute VB_Customizable = True
```

The GUID 0{00020820-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} is an exact match for `CoClass Worksheet`, as per OleViewer:

```
[
  uuid(00020820-0000-0000-C000-000000000046),
  helpcontext(0x0002a410)
]
coclass Worksheet {
    [default] interface _Worksheet;
    [default, source] dispinterface DocEvents;
};
```

The same behaviour occurs with the Workbook module. Here's the VBIDE exported text:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "ThisWorkbook"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
```

And the raw text from the IStream in the VBA binary:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "ThisWorkbook"
Attribute VB_Base = "0{00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Attribute VB_TemplateDerived = False
Attribute VB_Customizable = True
```

This time, as expected, the GUID `0{00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` is a Workbook CoClass:

```
[
  uuid(00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046),
  helpcontext(0x000305b8)
]
coclass Workbook {
    [default] interface _Workbook;
    [default, source] dispinterface WorkbookEvents;
};
```

The above is all good to know, but it doesn't solve your problem, unless you can get a handle to the in-memory IStreams for the components, which I don't think you can. If you can make do with loading the details from the last saved version of the host document, then you could load the details from the underlying document, but I don't think you want that, *and* it could end up being host-specific (consider the way that Access stores VBA in a table.)

However, the VBIDE *does* give you a clue about the CoClass. The properties collection for the vbComponent returns the *exact* number of properties that exist in the CoClass, and if you inspect the names, parameters and types of those properties, you'll find that they *exactly* match the members of the corresponding CoClass, right down to the order in which they occur in the CoClass defintion.

For example, the first 10 properties of a Worksheet vbComponent are:

```
Application
Creator
Parent
CodeName
_CodeName
Index
Name
Next
OnDoubleClick
OnSheetActivate
```

And the corresponding `propget` (and `propput`) entries from the dispinterface _Worksheet within CoClass Worksheet (with methods removed):

```
    [id(0x00000094), propget, helpcontext(0x0002a411)]
    Application* Application();
    [id(0x00000095), propget, helpcontext(0x0002a412)]
    XlCreator Creator();
    [id(0x00000096), propget, helpcontext(0x0002a413)]
    IDispatch* Parent();
    [id(0x0000055d), propget, helpcontext(0x0002a7fc)]
    BSTR CodeName();
    [id(0x80010000), propget, helpcontext(0x0002a7fd)]
    BSTR _CodeName();
    [id(0x80010000), propput, helpcontext(0x0002a7fd)]
    void _CodeName([in] BSTR rhs);
    [id(0x000001e6), propget, helpcontext(0x0002a7fe)]
    long Index();
    [id(0x0000006e), propget, helpcontext(0x0002a800)]
    BSTR Name();
    [id(0x0000006e), propput, helpcontext(0x0002a800)]
    void Name([in] BSTR rhs);
    [id(0x000001f6), propget, helpcontext(0x0002a801)]
    IDispatch* Next();
    [id(0x00000274), propget, hidden, helpcontext(0x0002a802)]
    BSTR OnDoubleClick();
    [id(0x00000274), propput, hidden, helpcontext(0x0002a802)]
    void OnDoubleClick([in] BSTR rhs);
    [id(0x00000407), propget, hidden, helpcontext(0x0002a803)]
    BSTR OnSheetActivate();
```

If you can reflect over the host Type Library's CoClasses and hash the property *names* (maybe just use the propget names), then you can compare the hash to that of the names in VBIDE's component.Properties collection.

It's a round-about way of getting the type, but without access to the IStream, I *think* it's going to be your only way.

Comment: That's very interesting... is there a neat way of getting that hidden GUID? Where is that IStream and why couldn't I access it? I think it would be the more robust solution; I think I'd rather fall back to matching the properties as a last resort.

Comment: The *persisted/disk* Stream is inside the `vbaProject.bin` structure, inside the host document. The *in-memory* (and therefore more current) Stream is in the host's process space, but I don't know of any way of getting hold of it. In other words, while you can load the Stream from disk, that only works for file-formats where you know where to find the VBA Storages and Streams, and it only works on the last saved version, so if the document has never been saved, or there are unsaved changes, you won't necessarily have all of the Streams.

Comment: I was only able to access the GUIDs because I decompressed the storages and streams in the vbaProject.bin file inside the XLSM document.

Comment: So, these wouldn't be accessible in an unsaved host document right?

Comment: correct. And even if the document had been saved previously, there might be new document-type components that haven't yet been saved (for example, a new Chart sheet won't exist in a vanilla workbook that has been saved. But the VBA storage is up to the host app. OpenXML formats use a compound file format, but Access uses system tables. Other hosts might use something else, so you end up needing host-specific solutions.

Comment: Oh, and just in case those attributes aren't already forbidden fruit, if you add an ActiveX control to a worksheet, then the Stream also has: `Attribute VB_Control = "CommandButton1, 1, 0, MSForms, CommandButton"`