# C# Excel VBA make module names not depended on the language

Tags: c#, vba, excel, com

```
excelFile.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
```

This code in English version of Office creates module named: "Module1". But if office language is different "Module1" will be in another language. I need to know how this module is called in my code.

```
var standardModule = excelFile.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("ThisWorkbook");
```

The same problem is here in English version of Office "ThisWorkbook" exits, but in another language it will be called differently.

It's possible to make this code language independent?

Comment: What object type is "ThisWorkbook"? A WorkBook or a module? EDIT: also can't you access it by index? would the index number vary?

Comment: @Innat3 It's a global `Workbook` instance representing the host document containing the code of the current VBA project.

Comment: that doesnt make any sense, the host document is already the variable "excelFile", with that piece of code I believe, you are trying to search a module with the name "ThisWorkbook"

Comment: @Innat3 every single Excel VBA project has a `ThisWorkbook` document module representing the host document, regardless of how much sense it makes.

Comment: The second part of the question is a Possible duplicate of [How to identify ThisWorkbook module using VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33485632/11683). The first part is correctly [answered below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39372165/11683).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is easy - `VBComponents.Add` returns a `VBComponent`.  You can just inspect the `.Name` property:

```
var module = excelFile.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
Debug.WriteLine(module.Name);
```

The second one is a bit trickier.  You'll need to loop through all of the VBComponents and test for the 2 things that are unique to the Workbook object.  It will have a `.Type` of `vbext_ct_Document` and 134 properties in its `.Properties` collection by default:

```
VBComponent thisWorkbook;
foreach (var module in excelFile.VBProject.VBComponents)
{
    var test = module as VBComponent;
    if (test.Type == vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_Document &&
        test.Properties.Count == 134)
    {
        thisWorkbook = test;
        Debug.WriteLine(thisWorkbook.Name);
        break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The Linq solution looks like this, but it's possible that you could leave dangling Interop references this way.  If you want to try it, it can't hurt - but it would be the first place I'd look if Excel doesn't shut down properly:

```
var thisWorkbook =
    (excelFile.VBProject.VBComponents).Cast<VBComponent>()
        .First(x => x.Type == vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_Document &&
                    x.Properties.Count == 134);
```

**EDIT2:** As pointed out by @Mat'sMug in the comments, the property count is specific to the version - the value above is probably specific to Excel 2013. For a new workbook, the ThisWorkbook module will be the one with the highest property count. This should work on any version:

```
VBComponent thisWorkbook = null;
foreach (var component in excelFile.VBProject.VBComponents.Cast<VBComponent>())
{
    if (thisWorkbook == null || component.Properties.Count > thisWorkbook.Properties.Count)
    {
        thisWorkbook = component;
    }
}
Debug.WriteLine(thisWorkbook.Name);
```

Linq:

```
var thisWorkbook =
    excelFile.VBProject.VBComponents.Cast<VBComponent>()
        .Aggregate((p, x) => (p.Properties.Count > x.Properties.Count ? p : x));
```

Comment: Oh, somehow I hadn't realized OP was also asking for a way to retrieve `ThisWorkbook`. Nice answer! =)

Comment: Is the property count 134 in all known versions of Excel?

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Now that you mention it, I would actually doubt it.  It should be fixed per version though.  134 is the value in 2013 (worksheets have 66 BTW).  It would probably be best to grab all the `VBComponent` of type `vbext_ct_Document`, group by `Properties.Count`, and take the result with the highest property count.  For a new workbook, that should be a safe assumption.

Comment: @WilliamCaman - Mat's Mug made a good point above - see the edit.

Comment: The search is not reliable and is not needed. Given a `Workbook excelFile`, the `ThisWorkbook`'s `VBComponent` is `excelFile.VBProject.VBComponents[excelFile.CodeName]`.

Comment: @GSerg - In this specific case, sure. But the presence of a `CodeName` property on the *Excel* object doesn't make the search unreliable.  AFAIK examining the properties is the only way to determine whether the underlying document module is a Workbook or a Worksheet when given an arbitrary `VBComponent`.  If you have a better method, the RD devs would love to know it.

Comment: @Comintern I don't quite understand. Both `Workbook` and `Worksheet` have a `CodeName` and the lookup works for them just as well. On contrary, the Excel object (which is `Excel.Application` I assume?) does not have a `CodeName`, but it is not associated with a code module either.

Comment: @GSerg see [how do I know that "ThisWorkbook" is a "Workbook"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37078992/1188513)

Comment: @GSerg - How do you get the `Excel.Workbook` object from an arbitrary `VBComponent`?  Using the `CodeName` property only works if you have access to the Excel object.  That's why I say that using the `CodeName` works fine *in this case* - but it has the underlying assumption that you hold the reference to the Workbook or Worksheet.

Comment: I will look into the reverse lookup, but I still don't understand why it's an issue to have to have a reference to Excel file. In the code in your answer, you have `excelFile` which is a `Workbook`, and you use it everywhere.

Comment: @GSerg - It's *not* an issue if you have access to the `excelFile`.  That fact that the solution above gets the `VBComponents` collection from the Workbook is only coincidental to the OP's code.  The test as to whether the `VBComponent` is a Workbook is intentionally meant to be a more general solution.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Okay, I think understand better. Then again, maybe I do not - because if you can't make assumptions on existence and structure of the host application, the how can you look up anything? Your absolute best is getting to the `VBProject` that contains the module (which is `component.Collection.Parent`), anything beyond that *requires* knowing that there must be a "Workbook" that must have the VBProject as its property. And still, this means this answer is much more confusing and less reliable *for the OP* than `VBComponents[excelFile.CodeName]`.

Comment: @GSerg - I agreed that *for the OP*, using the Excel object directly was easier about an hour ago.  You keep coming back to the "less reliable" assertion though.  `VBComponent.Properties.Count` per module type can be considered a constant for any given version of Excel - it's defined in the TypeLibrary and isn't effected by user code. Is there an example where sorting by property count *wouldn't* be reliable?

Comment: @Comintern I don't have an example, but I can't take the `For a new workbook, the ThisWorkbook module will be the one with the highest property count` for granted either. It just doesn't sound like it is based on something other than experiment. It may be true today, it might change with a next version. It sounds even less convincing when I try to apply it to a host-agnostic situation.

Comment: @GSerg - By that logic you can't take for granted that the next version of Excel won't remove the `CodeName` property.  The property count *can't* contain anything outside of the TypeLib, because that's not really the way that COM works. Anything that isn't a declared property of the document class would have to be on an extended interface. One of the rules for a dispatch interface is "The member and parameter DISPIDs must remain constant for the lifetime of the object." - it ***has to*** be bound to the defined interface in the TypeLib.

Comment: @Comintern It's nothing like removing properties from an interface. `Properties` is a collection that can be filled with any number of elements. Apparently you are saying that the `Properties` collection is always filled in a way that mirrors the typelib-declared properties of the parent, and their count always matches. I did not know that, but if that is the case, still in the next Excel version a Worksheet may contain more properties than a Workbook - because a bunch of properties can be added to the sheet with none removed from the workbook.

Comment: @GSerg - Right, and the next version of Excel could remove `CodeName`.  I think the likelihood of *either* of those things happening is approaching zero. ;-)

Comment: If you only have the component reference, then `TypeOf vbcomp.Properties("Parent").Object Is Application` will tell you if it is a Workbook, but how do you distinguish between a Chart sheet and a Worksheet? The Property count, in my testing, is more reliable *and* faster.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> excelFile.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
> ```

`VBComponents.Add` is a **function**, returning the object that was just added - but you're discarding that reference.

All you need to do is to hold on to that reference:

```
var component = excelFile.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
```

And then you can rename it at will (must be unique in the parent project though):

```
component.Name = "RenameMe";
```

...Or if you just need to know its name, it's right there for you to read:

```
Debug.WriteLine(component.Name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you just added that module in your code, it should be on the last index position, thus it should be accesible by doing:

```
VBComponent ModuleIJustAdded = excelFile.VBProject.VBComponents.Item(excelFile.VBProject.VBComponents.Count - 1);
```

Since you are unsure about the module's name, I suggest you try to play around the index.